# Laplace transform with Heaviside function

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I have been trying to preform laplace transformation on $10e^{0.5t-1}  u(t+2)$.

So here's how I tried to solve it using general formula for laplace transformation:

$
X(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 10e^{0.5t-1}e^{-st}  u(t+2)dt 
$

$
X(s) = \int_{-2}^{\infty} 10e^{t*(0.5-s)-1}dt
$

$
X(s) = -\frac{10e^{2s-2}}{0.5-s}
$

But this seems to be wrong answer, so I am confused now because when I run the problem on wolframalpha i get the answer:

$
\frac{3.67879}{s-0.5}
$

I am realy trying to understand what's going on here, because I get the wrong answer every time I try to solve it and I can't see where is mistake, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have t*t in your second formula

Comment: WA evaluated the unilateral Lapalce transform. For $\Re(s-c) > 0$ : $$\int_a^\infty b e^{ct} e^{-st}dt = b\frac{ e^{(c-s)t}}{c-s}|_a^\infty = -b\frac{ e^{(c-s)a}}{c-s}$$

Comment: @reuns how to evaluate 10e^2s-2 to 3.67879?

Comment: I'm saying WA evaluated the integral I wrote with $a=0$, obtaining $\frac{-b}{c-s}$